# Microcontroller internal Clock frequency tolerances

Tags: microcontroller, frequency, clock, timing, pll

I am having this microcontroller - [S32K142 64 Pin 5V Core voltage](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K-DS.pdf)

[Microcontroller Reference Manual](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/S32KReferenceManual.1978847578/view)

I want to use the FIRC and want to see the frequency tolerance of the FIRC.

Can someone help to find how to find the frequency tolerances of the internal clocks? Like SIRC, FIRC and the clock that can obtained after the PLL?

I couldn't find the frequency tolerances of the internal clocks

Comment: Didn't we already go through the tolerances in your previous question, "Bit error rate calculation for LIN protocol", to which you have not commented anything since my last edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tolerances are listed in the datasheet, pages 40 and 41.

Comment: Thank you.. Suppose, if the clock is obtained through PLL division? Suppose I derive 8MHz from the 48MHz, then the Tolerance deviation of the frequency will also be the same, right?

Comment: Yes. The PLL only multiplies the frequency. If the input is 1% lower than it should be, so will the output.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.